# Laravel Eloquent relationship missing on some objects

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables: `Garments` & `Properties`.

They have a manytomany relationship.

I am trying to retrieve the garments with properties attached using the following query:

```
$g = garment::with('properties')->get();
```

```
Garment.php:

public function properties(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property');
    }

Property.php:

public function garments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Garment');
    }
```

Pivot table: `garment_property` with foreign keys : `garment_id` and `property_id`

It returns all rows, but some objects do not return with properties (only 8 of 108 are the issue), even though they have existing relationships.

But if select the specific object with the following, it returns an array with the correct data:

```
$props=garment::where('name','tshirt')->first()->properties;
```

I can't tell what the rogue issue is. Hoping to get help with this.

Comment: Can you show your model relationship?

Comment: @DilipHirapara here you go.

Comment: Are you respecting the laravel conventions for tables and foriegn keys naming? I suppose your pivot table is named `germent_property`and foreign keys are `germent_id`and `property_id`. Also are you using soft deletes ??

Comment: @YezanRafed Correct, `garment_property` is the pivot table, and foreign kets are `garment_id` and `property_id`. I am not using soft deletes the way laravel has it set up. I have a column named 'is_active', that I toggle `true` and `false`.

Comment: Hmm that's weird !! Make sure you don't have a global scope in one of your two models... otherwise can you post your DB scripts (schema and data) ? I will try to replicate your scenario.

Comment: @YezanRafed The cause of concern is an object with the name 'tshirt'. And when I run `$props=garment::where('name','tshirt')->first()->properties;`  it give me what I need. Does '->with()' have outstanding issues?